# Can I lock a folder so NOBODY can delete it?

Tags: permissions, directory

I would like to create a folder in my OPT directory on Ubuntu 14.04. However, it must have the following requirements:

- Can not be deleted by ANYONE, even root.
- ReadOnly access to ALL users (except `nobody`)
- Write access ONLY by my user (`test-user`). Root shouldn't be able to write.

Comment: The only way root won't be able to delete  or modify a file is if the filesystem is mounted read only. Since you need write access, it follows that this is impossible.

Comment: Whatever the trick (filesystem read-only, using `attr`, ...) you use, root will still be able to overrule it. (remounting the filesystem read-write, removing the extended attributes, ...). So, strictly speaking, your first point will never be achieved.

Comment: I would not even bother @Benoit and just format it _O-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can not be deleted by ANYONE, even root.

Nope. root can always remount the disk or (better) remove any restrictions you put into place.

> ReadOnly access to ALL users (except nobody)

See 3.

> Write access ONLY by my user (test-user). Root shouldn't be able to write.

Nope. root can always remove any restrictions you put into place. You can mount (example: //youserver/sharename /mnt/mountpoint cifs username=yourusername,password=yourpassword,file_mode=0664,dir_mode=0775) a partition for a user but not block root access.

---

root can always (and has to always be able to) change anything that can form any sort of restriction. Otherwise you can end up with an unusable system that can only be formatted to get it working again.

If you have a root user that you do not trust then change the password and force them of the system. Otherwise this is moot: you will have to trust your admin.

Answer (score 4):

Following is possible:

If you have directory named `dir1` then use `chattr` as follows:

```
sudo chattr +i dir1
```

From `man chattr`:

> A file with the `i' attribute cannot be modified: it cannot be deleted or renamed, no link can be created  to  this  file.

**Now If any user even with sudo/root! try to delete this directory by CLI or GUI, it gives error: `Operation not permitted`.**

It is required to remove `i` attribute (which can be only done by root) as following command to give back rights to `dir1`:

```
sudo chattr -i dir1.
```

For any other case such as `rwx` permission and ownership can be applied by `chown` and `chmod` commands. 
*But wite-access by `test-user` and can't be deleted by even `root` at same time, seems **not possible!***